# Type annotations for restricting a wrapper class

Tags: python

I am writing a wrapper class, a wrapper in the sense that it wraps another type. It is a monad of sorts, but that is not important for my question, it is just a generic class that extends another type in various ways.

The simplest example I can think of looks like this:

```py
class Wrap(Generic[T]):
    """Wrap a value of type T."""

    val: T

    def __init__(self, val: T) -> None:
        """Wrap a value."""
        self.val = val
```

I want any `Wrap[T]` to mostly behave like a `T`, except for the cases where the extended functionality comes into play, so among other things I would like `Wrap[T]` to support the same operators as `T`.

If, for example, `x < y` is defined for `x: T, y: T`, then `x' < y'` should be defined for `x': Wrap[T], y': Wrap[T]`.

I don't know if I can statically and generically check if a type supports an operator, but I can write protocols for the operators. For less than, for example, I can write

```py
class Ordered(Protocol):
    """Types that support < comparison."""

    def __lt__(self: Ord, other: Ord) -> bool:
        """Determine if self is < other."""
        ...


Ord = TypeVar('Ord', bound=Ordered)
```

and that works as I expect it to:

```py
def f(x: Ord) -> None:
    """Do nothing."""
    print('nothing done,', x)


class Bar:
    """Nothing to see here."""


f(1)
f("foo")
# f(lambda x: x) # type error, ok
# f(Bar)         # type error, ok
# f(Bar())       # type error, ok
```

The last three calls to `f()` are marked as incorrectly typed, because a lambda, a type and a `Bar` doesn't support `<`.

Excellent.

Then my hope was that I could use the protocol in the wrapper class like this:

```py
class Wrap(Generic[T]):
    """Wrap a value of type T."""

    val: T

    def __init__(self, val: T) -> None:
        """Wrap a value."""
        self.val = val

    def __lt__(self: Wrap[Ord], other: Wrap[Ord]) -> bool:
        """Compare wrapped."""
        return self.val < other.val
```

but the type checking (with `mypy` at least) thinks that *any* wrapped object now supports `<`.

```py
print(Wrap(1) < Wrap(2))
print(Wrap("foo") < Wrap("bar"))
print(Wrap(lambda x: x) < Wrap(lambda x: x))  # should be error!
print(Wrap(Bar) < Wrap(Bar))                  # should be error!
print(Wrap(Bar()) < Wrap(Bar()))              # should be error!
```

The last three `print()` calls fly right through the type checker without raising any warnings.

It does make sense, since `Wrap` does implement `__lt__()`, I had just expected that the type annotation on its `__lt__()` would restrict which wrapped types I could use with `<`.

I based that assumption on what happens if I use a concrete type instead of a protocol in the type annotation. If I say that `__lt__()` is only defined for `Wrap[int]` then that is the only type that the type checker will allow:

```py
class Wrap(Generic[T]):
    """Wrap a value of type T."""

    val: T

    def __init__(self, val: T) -> None:
        """Wrap a value."""
        self.val = val

    def __lt__(self: Wrap[int], other: Wrap[int]) -> bool:
        """Compare wrapped."""
        return self.val < other.val


print(Wrap(1) < Wrap(2))                      # Ok
print(Wrap("foo") < Wrap("bar"))              # type error
print(Wrap(lambda x: x) < Wrap(lambda x: x))  # type error
print(Wrap(Bar) < Wrap(Bar))                  # type error
print(Wrap(Bar()) < Wrap(Bar()))              # type error
```

Similar for `str`:

```py
class Wrap(Generic[T]):
    """Wrap a value of type T."""

    val: T

    def __init__(self, val: T) -> None:
        """Wrap a value."""
        self.val = val

    def __lt__(self: Wrap[str], other: Wrap[str]) -> bool:
        """Compare wrapped."""
        return self.val < other.val


print(Wrap(1) < Wrap(2))                      # type error
print(Wrap("foo") < Wrap("bar"))              # Ok
print(Wrap(lambda x: x) < Wrap(lambda x: x))  # type error
print(Wrap(Bar) < Wrap(Bar))                  # type error
print(Wrap(Bar()) < Wrap(Bar()))              # type error
```

It is even happy with callable

```py
class Wrap(Generic[T]):
    """Wrap a value of type T."""

    val: T

    def __init__(self, val: T) -> None:
        """Wrap a value."""
        self.val = val

    def __lt__(self: Wrap[Callable[[Any], Any]],
               other: Wrap[Callable[[Any], Any]]) -> bool:
        """Compare wrapped."""
        return self.val < other.val  # type error


print(Wrap(1) < Wrap(2))                      # type error
print(Wrap("foo") < Wrap("bar"))              # type error
print(Wrap(lambda x: x) < Wrap(lambda x: x))  # Ok
print(Wrap(Bar) < Wrap(Bar))                  # type error
print(Wrap(Bar()) < Wrap(Bar()))              # type error
```

although it does, correctly, warn me that I am using `<` on two callables inside the method.

Is there anything I can do to use a protocol to restrict which wrapped types support which operators, the way I can restrict which concrete types are supported? Or is this the wrong way to go about restricting a wrapper class?

**Update**

Here's a few more examples that might hint at where the trouble is.

```py
class Wrap(Generic[T]):
    """Wrap a value of type T."""

    val: T

    def __init__(self, val: T) -> None:
        """Wrap a value."""
        self.val = val

    def __lt__(self: Wrap[X], other: Wrap[X]) -> bool:
        """Compare wrapped."""
        return self.val < other.val

    def f(self: Wrap[T], _x: Wrap[Ord]) -> None:
        """Test."""
        return

    def g(self: Wrap[Ord], _x: Wrap[S]) -> None:
        """Test."""
        return


# these should be okay since _x is Wrap[int] so Wrap[Ord]
Wrap(1).f(Wrap(1))    # Ok
Wrap(Bar).f(Wrap(1))  # Ok

# these should not be okay since _x is Wrap[Bar]
Wrap(1).f(Wrap(Bar))      # Error -- which we want
Wrap("foo").f(Wrap(Bar))  # Error -- which we want

# These should be okay since self is Wrap[int]
Wrap(1).g(Wrap(1))    # Ok
Wrap(1).g(Wrap(Bar))  # Ok, _x is Wrap[S] but that's fine

# These should not okay since self is Wrap[Bar] which isn't Wrap[Ord]
Wrap(Bar).g(Wrap(1))    # Ok, but *shouldn't be*
Wrap(Bar).g(Wrap(Bar))  # Ok, but *shouldn't be*
```

The type checker is happy to catch when the second argument in the method `f()` is not `Wrap[Ord]`, so it does agree that shouldn't be valid. But for `g()`, it doesn't catch that `self` should be `Wrap[Ord]` but rather will accept anything.

I usually don't have a problem with treating `self` a little special, but in this particular case I am not that happy about it...

Comment: If you are defining `__lt__` on `Wrap` then `T` should have `bound=Ordered`. This is the same as replacing `T` with `Ord` as your generic param.  If you do that then we can see it working with the desired properties here https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=e94673bd9e895420cec61ea26b94029f

Comment: But I don’t want Wrap to only wrap Ord types. It should wrap any type but only define < when the wrapped type is Ord. if T doesn’t define <, then Wrap shouldn’t either. The problem is to restrict which operations Wrap support based on the underlying type. Requiring that Wrap only wraps types that support all operators is not what I want. That I can easily do the way you propose. I don’t know how to selectively support some but not all operators.

Comment: _"if T doesn’t define <, then Wrap shouldn’t either"_ you need to write code that implements that, the type system alone cannot do it... currently Wrap always defines `__lt__`

Comment: I can define < so only Wrap[int] supports less than. Or only wrapped strings. Or any specific type. So it does support some of that. But apparently it doesn’t work for a protocol. For concrete types it does, in the examples I listed.

Comment: Well, weirdly it worked for Callable which is also a kind of protocol I guess. But not for Ordered for some reason

Comment: hmm, seems like a bug in mypy!  `def f(x: Wrap[Ord]) -> None: return` and `f(Wrap(lambda x: x))` will give _Value of type variable "Ord" of "f" cannot be "Callable[[Any], Any]"_ so that much works too

Comment: It does look like this is only an issue with methods and it looks like it is only a problem for `self` in methods. I just updated the question with an example of this.

Comment: It looks a lot like this issue, in which case it probably is a `mypy` bug: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11167