# Type checking wrapped functions with protocol arguments

Tags: python, mypy

I'm working on some code where I have wrapper functions that lift functions from type `T` to `Optional[T]`, but when I use a type that is a protocol, something goes wrong.

For example, I could have something like this:

```py
from typing import (
    TypeVar,
    Callable as Fn,
    Optional as Opt,
    Protocol,
    Any,
)
from functools import (
    wraps
)

_T = TypeVar('_T')

# Lifting a general function of type T x T -> T
def lift_op(f: Fn[[_T, _T], _T]) -> Fn[[Opt[_T], Opt[_T]], Opt[_T]]:
    """Lift op."""
    @wraps(f)
    def w(x: Opt[_T], y: Opt[_T]) -> Opt[_T]:
        return x if y is None else y if x is None else f(x, y)
    return w
```

to lift an operator `op: T x T -> T` to `Opt[T] x Opt[T] -> Opt[T]`. (I've shortened `Optional` and `Callable` to `Opt` and `Fn` to get shorter lines, nothing more).

This seems to work okay, mostly, but if I have a function that works on a generic type restricted to a protocol, something breaks.

Say I have a function that needs my type to support `<`. I can then use the protocol

```py
# Protocol for types supporting <
class Ordered(Protocol):
    """Types that support < comparison."""

    def __lt__(self: Ord, other: Any) -> bool:
        """Determine if self is < other."""
        ...


Ord = TypeVar('Ord', bound=Ordered)
```

and define a `min` function as

```py
# Min for two optionals
def min_direct(x: Opt[Ord], y: Opt[Ord]) -> Opt[Ord]:
    return x if y is None else y if x is None else \
           y if y < x else x # on ties choose x
```

and if I call it with two integers

```py
# mypy accepts that ints are Opt[Ord]
min_direct(1, 2)  # No problem here
```

mypy will accept that `int` is an `Opt[Ord]`.

But if I use the lift function, it breaks:

```py
@lift_op
def lift_min(x: Ord, y: Ord) -> Ord:
    """Return min of x and y."""
    return y if y < x else x

# Now int is no longer an Opt[Ord]!
lift_min(1, 2)    # Type error for both args.
```

I get the errors

```
error: Argument 1 to "lift_min" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Optional[Ord]"
error: Argument 2 to "lift_min" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Optional[Ord]"
```

So apparently `int` isn't an `Opt[Ord]` in this context.

It is fine if I write a `min` function specifically for `int`

```py
# Lifting a function with a concrete type (int) instead
# of a protocol
@lift_op
def imin(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    """Hardwire type to int."""
    return x if x <= y else y

# Again int is Opt[Ord]
imin(1, 2)  # All is fine here...
```

or if I specify the type of the wrapped function explicitly:

```py
# Try setting the type of the lifted function explicitly    
def lift_min_(x: Ord, y: Ord) -> Ord:
    """Return min of x and y."""
    return y if y < x else x

f: Fn[[Opt[Ord],Opt[Ord]], Opt[Ord]] = lift_op(lift_min_)
f(1, 2) # No problem here
```

I suspect that the return type of the `lift_op` wrapper isn't the same `Fn[[Opt[Ord],Opt[Ord]],Opt[Ord]]` as the type annotation for `f` above, but I'm not sure in what way. It isn't the `wraps()` call, that doesn't make a difference. But perhaps the `Ord` type gets bound somehow and is then interpreted differently?

I don't know, and I don't know how to figure it out. What do I need to do to make the wrapper function work so it will accept an `int`, say, as satisfying the protocol `Opt[Ord]`?

If you want the code in context, [here is a playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=ad7e107bcff816843a0d68072cb6ca9f)

Comment: Why you just don't pass `def lift_min(x: Ordered, y: Ordered) -> Ordered: ...`?)

Comment: @sudden_appearance because comparing `int` to `str` probably isn't intended...

Comment: Correct. I don't want `Ordered x Ordered -> Ordered` because I want all three types to be the same, not just three random types that support less than.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like `mypy` bug, unfortunately. Your `Ord` type var gets resolved on decorator level, because `T` appears both on left and right sides of decorator def. It is partially correct (you do really want to confirm that `T` is the same in original and transformed functions), but makes this variable unbound. That's why your attempt with assignment works: when you do

```py
f: Fn[[Opt[Ord], Opt[Ord]], Opt[Ord]] = lift_op(lift_min_)
```

you make `Ord` bound again. I think you should recheck `mypy` issue tracker and submit this bug if it was not done before (I was unable to find).

To reproduce this bug, you can use even simple type variables without restrictions:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Callable as Fn, Optional as Opt

_T = TypeVar('_T')

def allow_none(f: Fn[[_T], _T]) -> Fn[[Opt[_T]], Opt[_T]]:
    return f  # type: ignore

@allow_none
def simple(x: _T) -> _T:
    return x

reveal_type(simple)  # N: Revealed type is "def (Union[_T`-1, None]) -> Union[_T`-1, None]"
simple(1)  # E: Argument 1 to "simple" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Optional[_T]"
```

Now almost any type (except for `Any` and specific type vars) can not be passed as `simple` argument, because it is not `_T`. Bound variables are represented like `` def [_T] (Union[_T`-2, None]) -> Union[_T`-2, None] ``.

Here is [related mypy issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1317), but it doesn't cover exactly your case, so it would be great to report this separately (it may lead to raising priority and faster fix from maintainers). This bug reproduces with `pyre` too, so probably I'm misunderstanding something - but it really looks odd, type variable that should be bound within `Callable` is not bound any more.

I have tried a few solutions involving `Generic` and `Protocol`, but none of them seem to work: type var binding in function definition is strict enough and callable with type variable from `Generic` behaves really odd, resolving to `<nothing>` in `Union` context (don't kill me for lowercase class naming, it is too similar to `classmethod` or `property` and left lowercase intentionally):

```py
class _F(Protocol[_T]):
    def __call__(self, __x: _T) -> _T:
        ...

# Fails
class allow_none(Generic[_T]):
    def __call__(self, f: _F[_T], /) -> _F[_T | None]:
        return f  # type: ignore

reveal_type(allow_none[Ord]().__call__)  # N: Revealed type is "def (__main__._F[Ord?]) -> __main__._F[None]"

# But this works for some reason
class allow_none(Generic[_T]):
    def __call__(self, f: _F[_T], /) -> _F[_T]:
        return f  # type: ignore

reveal_type(allow_none[Ord]().__call__)  # N: Revealed type is "def (__main__._F[Ord?]) -> __main__._F[Ord?]"
```

It is probably a bug too, I'll report it asap.

For me your initial attempt with 2-step definition looks like the best workaround, unfortunately.

I also suggest to have a look at [`returns` library](https://returns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/maybe.html) by Nikita Sobolev - this link points to `Maybe` container that deals with your use case. Although I don't really like it, some people consider it better alternatives to chain of `is None` checks. It comes with typing for such cases (almost) for free.

Comment: Thanks. I'll report it to mypy issues. I do have a `Maybe` monad implementation, but there it is convenient with operator overloading, and I ran into trouble with type checking there as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72434219/type-annotations-for-restricting-a-wrapper-class I'm still working on it, though.